# Remove MS word decorative line

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2003

I am working on a document, based on a template i received from a friend, which contained a decorative line at the bottom, as you can see in the picture.

I have to delete that particular line to deliver my final version of the document, but i don't have any idea how to do it. I am using the 2003 edition of MS Word.

[image: word 2003 decorative line]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is in the footer,

Either double click the 'footer' select the image and press delete.

or

In the top bar, select 'view' and 'Headers and Footers'